# Np.where based on the values in the next rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rows

I have sample dataframe as follows

I just want to mark all the rows where id == 11 preeceded by 2.
If the id ==11 and does not preeced by 2 in the immediate rows I want to mark it as 0

```
Home"   Date       Time      id  Appliance   Banana expected_output output_from the code
1      1/21/2017    1:30:00  11   Apple       0       1                 1
2      1/21/2017    1:45:00  11  Apple        0       1                 1
3      1/21/2017    2:00:00  11  Apple        0       1                 1
4      1/21/2017    2:15:00  2   Banana       1       1                 0
5      1/21/2017    2:30:00  2   Banana       0       0                 0
6      1/21/2017    2:45:00  0   Orange       0       0                 0
7      1/21/2017    3:00:00  1   Peach        0       0                 0
8      1/21/2017    3:15:00  1   Peach        0       0                 0
9      1/21/2017    3:30:00  3   Pineapple    0       0                 0
10     1/21/2017    3:45:00  3   Pineapple    0       0                 0
11     1/21/2017    4:00:00  11  Apple        0       0                 1
12     1/21/2017    4:15:00  11  Apple        0       0                 1
13     1/21/2017    4:30:00  11  Apple        0       0                 1
14     1/21/2017    4:45:00  0   Orange       0       0                 0
15     1/22/2017    3:30:00  1   Peach        0       0                 0
16     1/22/2017    3:45:00  1   Peach        0       0                 0
17     1/22/2017    4:00:00  3   Pineapple    0       0                 0
18     1/22/2017    4:15:00  3   Pineapple    0       0                 0
19     1/22/2017    4:30:00  11  Apple        0       1                 1
20     1/22/2017    4:45:00  11  Apple        0       1                 1
21     1/22/2017    5:00:00  11  Apple        0       1                 1
22     1/22/2017    5:15:00  2   Banana       1       1                 0
23     1/22/2017    5:30:00  2   Banana       1       0                 0
```

what I have achieved so far

```
df['Banana'] = np.where((df['id']==2) & (df['id'].shift(+1)==11), 1,
                                   0)

formatted_df['output_from the code'] = np.where((df['id']==11) & (df['id'].shift(-1)==2), 1,
                                    np.where((df['id']==11) & (df['id'].shift(-1)==11), 1,
                                   0))
```

is there a way to write np.where based on previous row

Comment: `np.where` is not a row iterator.  All arguments are evaluated in full before being passed to the function.  As such it is only as useful as the condition array/series the you write.

Comment: "Followed by 2" or "succeeded by 2". Preceded means the 2 comes before.

Comment: I actually upvoted your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a utility library I maintain called [haggis](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It has two functions that convert an array of booleans to an array of run markers and vice versa called [`haggis.math.mask2runs`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#haggis.math.mask2runs) and [`haggis.math.runs2mask`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#haggis.math.runs2mask), respectively. The functions are inverses of each other. `mask2runs` works like this:

```
>>> mask2runs([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 6],
       [7, 9]], dtype=int64)
```

The first column is the start indices of each run of True elements, and the second column is the exclusive end. You can use this directly:

```
# Grab locations of 11s
runs = mask2runs(df.id == 11)
# remove the ones that aren't followed by 2
runs = runs[df.id.iloc[np.clip(runs[:, 1], 0, len(df) - 1)] == 2]
# Convert remaining runs back to mask
df.output = runs2mask(runs, n=len(df))
```

You don't need to import haggis to use these functions. They are actually pretty simple, especially in this limited usecase. The source is [here](https://github.com/madphysicist/haggis/blob/dev/src/haggis/math.py), but you can also summarize them as follows specifically for this problem:

```
def mask2runs(mask):
    return np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[np.int8(0), mask.view(np.int8) np.int8(0)])).reshape(-1, 2)

def runs2mask(runs, n):
    mask = np.zeros(n, dtype=bool)
    view = mask.view(np.int8)
    view[runs[:, 0]] = 1
    view[runs[:-1, 1] if runs[-1, 1] == n else runs[:, 1]] = -1
    np.cumsum(view, out=view)
    return mask
```